# Can't set supervisord error logging level to debug

Tags: linux, logging, supervisord

I'm trying to debug a spawn error with supervisord and I want to set the error logging level to "debug" so I can pin down the cause of the ENOENT error it's throwing. So far no luck.

I'm working on a Linode Ubuntu 18.04 VPS. According to the Supervisor docs, setting the error level in /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf is a simple matter. Here's part of that file:

```
[supervisord]
user=www
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
loglevel=debug
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor
.
.
.
[program:my_app]
command=/. . . . .
directory=/home/deployer/sites/flask/my_app
loglevel=debug
user=www
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
stopsignal=QUIT
redirect_stderr=false
```

After adding the `loglevel=debug` lines to the conf file, I ran `sudo supervisorctl reread` and it claimed `No config updates to processes` (it seems to only acknowledge changes to program blocks). I then ran `sudo supervisorctl update` and `sudo supervisorctl start my_app`. The reply was `my_app: ERROR (spawn error).` I tried this process several times to double and triple check everything. Both log files are showing only INFO entries or higher. No debug entries at all.

Of course what I want is to go to the logs and get more feedback than just:
`couldn't exec /home/deployer/sites/flask/my_app/venv/bin/gunicorn: ENOENT` Naturally, I'd like to know just what file or directory it says it can't find. It may be a slip of a character or some other dumb thing, but I need more debug information to track that down. So how do I get supervisor to produce some actual debug information? Mind you, I'm not asking (yet) what's wrong with my whole flask-gunicorn-supervisor problem, just how to get some useful debug information into the logs.

Many thanks!